# Memorystore Session and Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-memorystore

I have a few functions and I share user session among the functions using Cloud Memorystore. I used connect-redis package and I modified it to work with Memorystore.

It works without issues mostly. However, I have found that at times, the cloud functions were unable to access the session. It doesn't happen frequently and I have faced this issue maybe three to four times in the last one and a half month. There are no errors in the functions and I have rigorously checked my functions.

I have always found that redeploying the functions, even without any changes to the code fixes the issue. I have only been working with GCP products for over two months now and I am not sure if these two products are incompatible or are there any edge cases that are being triggered that results in the following issue.

Due to sudden nature of the error I am also not sure if I can replicate the events leading to the error. What can I do to debug this error and have a more concrete understanding of what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview#connecting) the usage of Cloud Functions with Memorystore should work normally without any issues.

It could be caused by many factors. Possibly connection timeout, cold start of the Function, maybe misuse of Memorystore leading to an issue there preventing it from working as expected.

What I suggest is that you add logging before and after every part of the code that completes a big part.
So basically try to locate which parts of the code are causing the issue or not showing expected results when the issue occurs, then split that part into smaller parts to find what is causing the issue. If even with logging everything seems okay with the Cloud Function, most likely something is going on on Memorystore side.

It might also be worth it then to open a Public Issue for further investigation if the issue seems to be something irrelevant to your code or configuration. [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have been digging into the issue myself. What I suspect is the policy for my redis instance. It was set to `volatile-lru` and I changed it to `noeviction`. No errors since then but I will check more before confirming. As for logging, the issue starts when the first middleware in the chain that checks for session fails to load a session from MemoryStore redis instance. From the log, I can always see that in such cases, the session object is empty.

Comment: Seems like a possible cause I'd say. Hopefully that will prevent the issue from happening again.